# Can flash.display.Bitmap have events on themself?

Tags: actionscript, bitmap

Is this possible or need I do it anyway else? The problem is that the event is not responding.

```
  [Embed(source="pic1.jpg")]
    private var Img1:Class; 

    var i1:Bitmap = new Img1();

   // not working 

    i1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent) {
        t.htmlText = "Click!"; 
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html), Bitmap is not descendant of [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html). Only interactive objects can be part of an input processes of Flash.

To do what you want encapsulate the Bitmap with Sprite:

```
[Embed(source="pic1.jpg")]
private var Img1:Class; 

var i1:Bitmap = new Img1();
var s1:Sprite = new Sprite();

s1.addChild(i1);    

s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent) {
    t.htmlText = "Click!"; 
});
```

Comment: Why can't you set a width and height on the image or sprite? What's the best solution for resizing images? I did for a couple of years ago a imagegallery solution in flash with as3 and everything was movieclips. But now I thought to do a solution in pure as-project in flash builder. Is it many differences between sprite and movieclips. Maybe movieclips has lots more functionality than a Sprite?

Comment: @marko You can set width & height of sprite just as anything else, the end result is as if you modified the scaleX & scaleY values though. Depending on your needs, using Width/Height or scaleX/scaleY (the latter is less human error prone to be honest). The only difference between Sprite & MovieClip is that the latter can have multiple frames, which is of no use in AS-only environment (unless you are loading MCs exported from Flash Professional). Use Sprite if you don't need this functionality.